# AngularJS: blur event not firing in directive for form validation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Using Angular, I am working on a registration form which also features an input field for username. I wrote a directive to check the username for „uniqueness“ on server-side upon field blur.

This is my Angular code:

```
App.directive('usernameCheck', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on('blur', function (evt) {          
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/usernameCheck/', <-- NEVER ACCESSED!?
                        data: {'username' : $scope.userName}
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('unique', data.status);
                    });
                });
            });  
        }
    }
}]);
```

And the HTML form input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userName" name="userName" username-check required>
```

For some strange reason, the directive does not seem to work. There is no JS error occurring but the blur element does not fire - according to Firebug, the server route „/usernameCheck“ is never called. What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you make use of the `ng-blur` Angular directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: I guess, I just wanted to dive into writing custom directives =)

Answer (score 0):

try with the `ng-blur`approach (simple generic example):

```
app.directive('directiveName', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngBlur: '&'
    },
    link:function(scope){    
      scope.onBlur = function(ev){
        console.log(ev);
      }    
   },    
   template: '<input ng-blur="onBlur($event)"></input>'
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried `elem.bind` as proposed earlier. Didn't work either... will keep trying.